# correspondence between differentiable line bundles and elements of $H_1(X,\epsilon^*)$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

On Well's book, lemma 4.4 says there is a one-to-one correspondence between the equivalence classes of holomorphic line bundles on $X$ and the elements of the cohomology group $H_1(X,\mathcal{O}^*)$, where $\mathcal{O}^*$ means non-vanishing  holomorphic structure sheaf.

Now I wonder if there is a one-to-one correspondence between the equivalence classes of differentiable line bundles on $X$ and the elements of the cohomology group $H_1(X,\epsilon^*)$, where $\epsilon^*$ means non-vanishing differentiable structure sheaf.

The proof of the first statement is here:

[image]

I think the second statement can be proved by mimicking the proof above, am I correct?

Comment: What's $\epsilon^*$?

Comment: @JohnMa non-vanishing structure differentiable sheaf

Comment: There is such a correspondence, but it might be easier to just say that they're classified by $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/2)$. ;) (Think about the exact sequence $\{\pm\} \to \epsilon^* \to \epsilon^{>0}$, and use the fact that the last sheaf has partitions of unity --- to be explicit, it's isomorphic to the sheaf of sections of the trivial line bundle.)